# What is the differences between GLI and CLI in linux from the kernel's perspective

Tags: linux, user-interface, command-line-interface

Can anyone tell me what is the differences between the GLI and CLI from a developer's perspective?

I also want to know how the linux system set up GLI and CLI after booting.

For CLI, when a new user login, after system booting, the process `init` dose a `fork`, in turn an `exec` of program `getty` is invoked for user login. After user entered username and password, the `getty` verifies the identity of current login user. If everything is OK, `getty` executes `execle` to load `login` program followed by invoking a shell.

But what does kernel do, when booting a graphic desktop.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: GLI?  Do you mean GUI?

Comment: I do mean GUI. But I think GLI is more precise than GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the kernel at all. It's about how `init` is configured and which of its runlevels is started. The command `pstree -u` is your friend.

```
 ├─mdm───mdm─┬─Xorg
 │           ├─x-session-manag(szg)─┬─applet.py───{applet.py}
 │           │                      ├─gpg-agent
 │           │                      ├─marco───2*[{marco}]
 │           │                      ├─mate-bluetooth-───2*[{mate-bluetooth-}]
 │           │                      ├─mate-panel───2*[{mate-panel}]
 │           │                      ├─mate-power-mana───2*[{mate-power-mana}]
 │           │                      ├─mate-screensave───2*[{mate-screensave}]
 │           │                      ├─mate-settings-d───4*[{mate-settings-d}]
 │           │                      ├─mate-volume-con───{mate-volume-con}
 │           │                      ├─mintupdate-laun───sh───mintUpdate───2*[{mintUpdate}]
 │           │                      ├─nm-applet───2*[{nm-applet}]
 │           │                      ├─notgmail───sleep
 │           │                      ├─polkit-mate-aut───{polkit-mate-aut}
 │           │                      ├─sh───caja───3*[{caja}]
 │           │                      ├─ssh-agent
 │           │                      ├─tapeta───sleep
 │           │                      ├─zeitgeist-datah───3*[{zeitgeist-datah}]
 │           │                      └─3*[{x-session-manag}]
 │           └─{mdm}
```

You can see a MATE desktop session above. `init` starts `mdm`, the MATE Desktop Manager as root, which in turn starts the Xorg X-server to handle the hardware and a session-manager where you log in, then it drops privileges and starts your user-level desktop services.

This does not happen instead of the `getty`s, but besides them. You can still log in on the CLI, with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> etc.